# Deleted "Valid" Answer

Tags: discussion, moderation, answer-quality

While doing review work I came across [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19702/is-it-possible-to-design-a-c-like-language-without-a-preprocessor), which has attached to it an answer deleted by "Community" (and as it's deleted by a mod, I can't vote to undelete).

It's not clear to me why it was deleted, the answer is valid in the sense that it attempts to answer the question (whether it's a good answer or not is irrelevant, that's what voting is for). It doesn't contain abuse or advertising.

Is there something here that I'm missing, but should be on the look-out for as a responsible user, or is there some behind-the-scenes issue, independent of the answer content?

Comment: Community != a mod

Comment: @Raphael, the mod part came from clicking on undelete, where it said it was deleted by a mod (perhaps this is erroneous anyway).

Comment: I guess that's because Community is implemented to have mod powers (and more, I guess). It's the system doing things in an automated fashion.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer was posted from an account that no longer exists. It was deleted automatically.

The answer is of low quality: it states that the answer is yes and cites an example language but does not cite what makes this example work. It is written in an evangelist style, rather than in the explanatory style that I would expect on a site which is about science. It is not necessarily wrong, per se, but it lacks substance that would make it interesting and useful, and its presentation is likely to arouse controversy.

I wouldn't normally delete this answer as a moderator — I would comment and request improvements on the basis given above — because it is not a clear-cut case. However I would vote to delete it as *very low quality* if I had a non-binding vote.

I'm not fundamentally adverse to undeleting it, but I think the site is better off without it.

Comment: Ah, the latter part is what I would expect, encouragement to improve, then/or a vote to delete if it's particularly bad. The dead account is the missing key! I'm not really in favour of undeleting it either, I was more interested in how it ended up that way when it didn't appear to have been through the normal process, and whether the reason that it was deleted was useful to know as someone trying to do a good job in helping maintain the site.